# What are some web based clients for GeoServer?

Tags: embeddable-web-maps, web-service, geoserver

There is a list of Web Clients for Geoserver on the Geoserver site (http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/Clients). Unfortunately, it is posted as no longer maintained.  Does anyone have a current list of web clients?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on which [services you want to provide/consume using Geoserver (WMS, WFS/WFS-T, or WCS)](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/services/index.html). Based on the services you want to use, you can look for suitable clients. [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/) is one of the most advanced tools and documentation is good.

Other clients include:

- [Mapstraction](http://www.mapstraction.com/)
- [MapBuilder](http://communitymapbuilder.osgeo.org/)
- [Mapbender](http://www.mapbender.org/Main_Page)
- [GeoExt](http://www.geoext.org/)
- [Mapfish](http://mapfish.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add:

- [BruTile](http://brutile.codeplex.com/) ([Mapsui](http://mapsui.codeplex.com/))
- [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/)
- [deegree](http://www.deegree.org/)

Answer (score 2):

you might also consider [openscales](http://openscales.org/) for flex/AIR based geoserver clients.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the most popular tool used to build Web clients for GeoServer is [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org)

You may also want to look at MapFish `http://mapfish.org/` and GeoExt `http://www.geoext.org/`.

Comment: MapFish and GeoEXT are still basically OpenLayers when it comes to the map.

Answer (score 1):

You might one to check one of the newest arrivals on the scene - [CartoView](https://github.com/cartologic/cartoview).

Comment: It's not clear to me that I can use a WMS/WFS in cartoview. All the examples seem to be limited to GoogleMaps.

Comment: this example http://www.cartologic.com/products/cartoview-1.0.0beta/samples/ol-layers/index.html provides a method of fetching geoserver layers [first icon on the right]

Answer (score -1):

I think we can use Mapserver in combination with openlayers as web client

Comment: Isn't the question about GeoServer?