# Displaying 1000 hiking trails with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, layers, performance

I am writing a web application to visualize a database of ~1000 hiking trails. All trails should be displayed simultaneously. Each trail should be individually clickable to view hiking information. I am considering GeoServer as a platform.

How should I structure the trail data if I decide to go with GeoServer? Should I merge all trails into a single layer, or have each trail in a separate layer? Would there be performance problems with the latter approach?

Comment: While GeoServer could be part of the solution, you really need to say how the client side will work. At least saying what kind of client you are planning to use would help.

Comment: @BradHards I would use one of GeoServer's [web clients](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/771/what-are-some-web-based-clients-for-geoserver) - I have not yet decided which one.

Comment: Only 1000 polylines is a very small dataset. I wouldn't worry about performance at all! Just do whatever is easier for you.

Answer (score 3):

Either you will use geoserver or other possible way like mapserver, you can do the following:
1) **Group all** trails in one layer. *(or if you want to show/Hide trails on your map based on categories, then create layer for each group)*.
2) Use **WMS** to get image of trails.
3) Use **WFS** to get feature information for selected location and get the trail information.

In reference to **loading time**, if trails are not updated frequently you may consider using mapcache to generate tiles and cache them, indeed loading not be an issue.